# Why we use thin films of lubricants if viscous forces are inversely proportional to separation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, friction, viscosity

When layers of fluid move relative to each other, viscosity creates frictional force.

wiki: magnitude of the force, F, acting on the top plate is found to be proportional to the speed u and the area A of each plate, and inversely proportional to their separation y:

$$
    F=\mu A{\frac {u}{y}}.
$$

Therefore the thinner the layer of fluid between two solid bodies, the more friction it should create. If y → 0 then F → ∞

Yet we use fluid-film lubrication for bearings and try to make those films as thin as possible. Sometimes it even creates a problems - when film is so thin that molecule size starts matter (boundary lubrication).

Why we use thin films of lubricants if viscous forces are inversely proportional to separation?

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of frictional forces caused by fluid shear in a lubricated bearing is far less than that caused by metal-to-metal contact in a dry bearing without lubrication present. Also, frictional losses in lubricated bearings represent a small price to pay for preventing damage to the rotating parts.

Comment: Also, in many kinds of bearings, the gap clearance  varies with position along the contact.  This causes the development off a normal force which keeps the surfaces separated at the desired  minimum gap.

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue of practicality. The goal is not zero friction without constraint, it is to have constrained motion with as little friction as possible without distorting the desired motion. Using a thin film lets you lower friction while also not impeding the desired motion. Of course, if you had a film which was too thick, then you would have that the parts you are lubricating no longer move in sync. Naturally, there is no single thickness which works in all cases. Furthermore, thick films also tend to spread lubricant in places where it is undesired.

When you lubricate a cooking pan for baking, you do not put excess oil just to make it extra easy for the cake to be removed because that would disturb the makeup and texture of the cake. You use as little oil as possible which allows you to easily remove the cake while not changing its makeup. A similar idea holds in general, low friction is one desired property, not the end all and be all.